# TestWriter and TextReader XML Simple

Tags: xml, vb.net

"Write 2 procedures using the XMLTestWriter and XMLTextReader Class that will create and display this XML File"

I am really stuck with this exam question and can't find any easy ways of writing this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucni4.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi Raw N, I forgot to mention that this is using VB.Net

Comment: I suggest you start here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbNy4Fzlmms and here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwGpzQV8ZZ4

Comment: Please post what code you've attempted so far, what problems you're seeing, and what you've attempted to do to resolve them.  This question in particular seems like it could mainly be accomplished by reading documentation on XMLTestWriter and XMLTextReader

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a very easy tricky question.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            reader.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer); 
            ds.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```